# Trouble getting regular expression to return given scraped website's text

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

So I scraped a website and now I'm trying to using RE to pull out certain parts of the text.

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.nasdaq.com/article/2017-small-cap-biotech-watchlist-takeaways-for-investors-cm739688')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.text)
```

yields something like:

```
In a panel discussion moderated by Maxim Group's senior managing director and the head of healthcare research Jason Kolbert, Raghuram "Ram" Selvaraju of Rodman & Renshaw; George Zavoico, senior equity analyst at JonesTrading Institutional Services; and Mike King, managing director and senior biotechnology analyst at JMP Securities, detailed their investment theses for the companies that made the cut.
King chose nine companies for the list, including OncoMed Pharmaceuticals Inc. (OMED:NASDAQ) , a company "we've had a long-term passion for." He considers OncoMed a "leader in the cancer stem cell space," with a number of clinical assets including a handful that are proprietary, and many partnered with larger-cap pharmas and biotechs. Among the candidates slated for either clinical trials or data readouts in 2017 is demcizumab, in pancreatic cancer. "We think it will be a key catalyst for the shares," King said. Other assets include tarextumab, for a small cell lung cancer; DLL4/VEG4, also in non-small cell lung cancer; and "a new asset that was previously known as I/O#2. . .a very highly validated immuno-oncology target called TIGIT," in development in partnership with Celgene Corp. (CELG:NASDAQ).
King called Syndax Pharmaceuticals Inc. (SNDX:NASDAQ) "a hybrid story. " The company is a player in the immuno-oncology space as well as in the "broader" cancer world with a drug called entinostat, which is in Phase 3 in metastatic breast cancer. Readouts on overall survival aren't expected until 2019, but King is "optimistic about Syndax's chances for success in the Phase 3 trial." The company is also in collaborations with major pharmas in the "immune checkpoint space," with data expected to "roll out over the course of 2017."
Syros Pharmaceuticals (SYRS:NASDAQ) is an early-stage company, with a ~$250M market cap, that King considers a leader in gene regulation, with a concept called super-enhancers. The company both develops its "own internal candidates to some of the highly validated targets," as well as repurposes assets that may have been abandoned for indications like blood disorders. Syros might be "a quiet story the first half of 2017, but I think in the second half of 2017, we'll start to see some fireworks based on the data that will read out through key assets, SY-1365 and SY-1425."
```

I'm trying to pull out the stock tickers which look like this:

```
(OMED:NASDAQ)
(SYRS:NASDAQ)
```

I'm trying

```
pattern = re.compile(r':\(\w+\)')
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.find_all(text =pattern))
```

but it's yielding

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

EDIT:

Also,tried
`pattern = re.compile(r'\(\w+:\w+\)' )` and `pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+:[A-Z]+)')'

both are yielding something like this:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['OncoMed Pharmaceuticals Inc. (OMED:NASDAQ)', ' , a company "we\'ve had a long-term passion for." He considers OncoMed a "leader in the cancer stem cell space," with a number of clinical assets including a handful that are proprietary, and many partnered with larger-cap pharmas and biotechs. Among the candidates slated for either clinical trials or data readouts in 2017 is demcizumab, in pancreatic cancer. "We think it will be a key catalyst for the shares," King said. Other assets include tarextumab, for a small cell lung cancer; DLL4/VEG4, also in non-small cell lung cancer; and "a new asset that was previously known as I/O#2. . .a very highly validated immuno-oncology target called TIGIT," in development in partnership with Celgene Corp. (CELG:NASDAQ).']
['King called Syndax Pharmaceuticals Inc. (SNDX:NASDAQ) "a hybrid story. " The company is a player in the immuno-oncology space as well as in the "broader" cancer world with a drug called entinostat, which is in Phase 3 in metastatic breast cancer. Readouts on overall survival aren\'t expected until 2019, but King is "optimistic about Syndax\'s chances for success in the Phase 3 trial." The company is also in collaborations with major pharmas in the "immune checkpoint space," with data expected to "roll out over the course of 2017."']
['Syros Pharmaceuticals (SYRS:NASDAQ) is an early-stage company, with a ~$250M market cap, that King considers a leader in gene regulation, with a concept called super-enhancers. The company both develops its "own internal candidates to some of the highly validated targets," as well as repurposes assets that may have been abandoned for indications like blood disorders. Syros might be "a quiet story the first half of 2017, but I think in the second half of 2017, we\'ll start to see some fireworks based on the data that will read out through key assets, SY-1365 and SY-1425."']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\(\w+:\w+\)' )
# This will match any words in range of [0-9a-zA-Z]
```

Example at:
https://regex101.com/r/P2yqzF/3

Maybe `re.findall(pattern, paragraph.text)` will solve your second problem

Comment: Tried it, but strangely I'm still getting a lot of text. I updated the OP with the result.

Comment: I updated the link, and I capture only correct values on regex101, What do you capture?

Comment: I updated the OP with the result I'm getting from trying your suggestion. I wonder if it's a Python thing?  I'm going to update with the site I scraped as well.

Comment: All sugested answers suggest the same regex, so maybe your fault lies elsewhere?

Comment: I'm updated the OP with the scrapped site and and code used to scrap the site. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Yeah it works with a couple of tweaks. Just update your second part(of the answer) with this `for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
      print(re.findall(pattern, paragraph.text))`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\([A-Z]+:[A-Z]+\)')
```

That looks for `<open parantheses><caps letter><colon><caps letter><close parantheses>`

Then, in order to find the string, you can do `re.findall(paragraph)`

(assuming paragraph is a string)

Comment: Strangely, I'm still getting a lot of text, similar to the output  when trying 
 `Ludisposed`  suggestion. I updated the OP.

Comment: using http://regexr.com/, I input your paragraph, and my regex, and captured only the target values; what is the "type" of the paragraph object?

Comment: I've updated the OP with the code and site I used to scrape the site. Maybe there is something there that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the result of `for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'): print(type(paragraph))` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
paragraphs = '''\
In a panel discussion moderated by Maxim Group's senior managing director and the head of healthcare research Jason Kolbert, Raghuram "Ram" Selvaraju of Rodman & Renshaw; George Zavoico, senior equity analyst at JonesTrading Institutional Services; and Mike King, managing director and senior biotechnology analyst at JMP Securities, detailed their investment theses for the companies that made the cut.
King chose nine companies for the list, including OncoMed Pharmaceuticals Inc. (OMED:NASDAQ) , a company "we've had a long-term passion for." He considers OncoMed a "leader in the cancer stem cell space," with a number of clinical assets including a handful that are proprietary, and many partnered with larger-cap pharmas and biotechs. Among the candidates slated for either clinical trials or data readouts in 2017 is demcizumab, in pancreatic cancer. "We think it will be a key catalyst for the shares," King said. Other assets include tarextumab, for a small cell lung cancer; DLL4/VEG4, also in non-small cell lung cancer; and "a new asset that was previously known as I/O#2. . .a very highly validated immuno-oncology target called TIGIT," in development in partnership with Celgene Corp. (CELG:NASDAQ).
King called Syndax Pharmaceuticals Inc. (SNDX:NASDAQ) "a hybrid story. " The company is a player in the immuno-oncology space as well as in the "broader" cancer world with a drug called entinostat, which is in Phase 3 in metastatic breast cancer. Readouts on overall survival aren't expected until 2019, but King is "optimistic about Syndax's chances for success in the Phase 3 trial." The company is also in collaborations with major pharmas in the "immune checkpoint space," with data expected to "roll out over the course of 2017."
Syros Pharmaceuticals (SYRS:NASDAQ) is an early-stage company, with a ~$250M market cap, that King considers a leader in gene regulation, with a concept called super-enhancers. The company both develops its "own internal candidates to some of the highly validated targets," as well as repurposes assets that may have been abandoned for indications like blood disorders. Syros might be "a quiet story the first half of 2017, but I think in the second half of 2017, we'll start to see some fireworks based on the data that will read out through key assets, SY-1365 and SY-1425."'''

import re
exp = re.compile(r'(\([A-Z]+\:[A-Z]+\))')

for para in paragraphs.split('\n'):
    print (para)
    print (exp.findall(para))
```

Results:

```
In a panel discussion moderated by Maxim Group's senior managing director and the head of healthcare research Jason Kolbert, Raghuram "Ram" Selvaraju of Rodman & Renshaw; George Zavoico, senior equity analyst at JonesTrading Institutional Services; and Mike King, managing director and senior biotechnology analyst at JMP Securities, detailed their investment theses for the companies that made the cut.
[]
King chose nine companies for the list, including OncoMed Pharmaceuticals Inc. (OMED:NASDAQ) , a company "we've had a long-term passion for." He considers OncoMed a "leader in the cancer stem cell space," with a number of clinical assets including a handful that are proprietary, and many partnered with larger-cap pharmas and biotechs. Among the candidates slated for either clinical trials or data readouts in 2017 is demcizumab, in pancreatic cancer. "We think it will be a key catalyst for the shares," King said. Other assets include tarextumab, for a small cell lung cancer; DLL4/VEG4, also in non-small cell lung cancer; and "a new asset that was previously known as I/O#2. . .a very highly validated immuno-oncology target called TIGIT," in development in partnership with Celgene Corp. (CELG:NASDAQ).
['(OMED:NASDAQ)', '(CELG:NASDAQ)']
King called Syndax Pharmaceuticals Inc. (SNDX:NASDAQ) "a hybrid story. " The company is a player in the immuno-oncology space as well as in the "broader" cancer world with a drug called entinostat, which is in Phase 3 in metastatic breast cancer. Readouts on overall survival aren't expected until 2019, but King is "optimistic about Syndax's chances for success in the Phase 3 trial." The company is also in collaborations with major pharmas in the "immune checkpoint space," with data expected to "roll out over the course of 2017."
['(SNDX:NASDAQ)']
Syros Pharmaceuticals (SYRS:NASDAQ) is an early-stage company, with a ~$250M market cap, that King considers a leader in gene regulation, with a concept called super-enhancers. The company both develops its "own internal candidates to some of the highly validated targets," as well as repurposes assets that may have been abandoned for indications like blood disorders. Syros might be "a quiet story the first half of 2017, but I think in the second half of 2017, we'll start to see some fireworks based on the data that will read out through key assets, SY-1365 and SY-1425."
['(SYRS:NASDAQ)']
```